# Java : Not sure if correct use of BigInteger

Tags: java, math, project, biginteger

This program is meant to calculate the sum x amount of prime numbers under n, yet my code doesnt seem to work, it compiles and there are no errors.When I run it the console is just blank

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Prime prime = new Prime();
    BigInteger answer = BigInteger.valueOf(0);
    for (int i = 2; i < 2000000; i++) {
        if (prime.isPrime(i)) {
            answer = answer.add(BigInteger.valueOf(i));

        }
    }

    System.out.println(answer);
}
```

isPrime method

```
  boolean isPrime(int n) {
    for(int i = 2; i < n ; i++) {
        if(n % i == 0) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: and this is working right? ***prime.isPrime(i)***

Comment: Yes it works for everything bigger than 2, the biggest number i tested so far was 200000 though

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: but wait... what should be the answer of that? I mean how are you verifying that is not working?

Comment: Im just looking for a solution to my problem. The problem is that it doesnt work when i run it on eclipse

Comment: Provide sample input and output cases

Comment: "My code doesn't seem to work" - in what way? Give more details, specifically the intended and actual results.

Comment: The console is just blank, nothing comes up

Comment: Can you post some more code to detailed explanation@AbdulwasiiAjayi

Comment: could you attach isPrime() method?

Comment: if you do System.out.println("answer " + answer); does it print?

Comment: If I do it in the for loop, it prints out a whole heap of numbers I couldnt even begin to count, but if i System.out.println("answer" + answer) at the end the console still remains blank.

Comment: if you change 2000000 to 100 does it make a difference?

Comment: Yes it works the way it is meant to

Comment: As @isaace touches upon.  I'm running your code locally and it doesn't finish the for loop quickly.  It hasn't finished in a minute.  How long are you giving your code to print the result?  After two minutes, i is 741710.

Comment: That's not the best way to determine prime: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes

Answer (score 1):

You are just not waiting long enough.

Try using `i < 200` and you'll see the answer `4227` print out quite quickly.

You are checking `2,000,000` numbers for primality. Your `isPrime` method is `O(n)` so you are doing approximately `2,000,000 * 1,000,000` calculations. You work it out.

Comment: That makes sense I guess, i just thought computers would be faster

Comment: @AbdulwasiiAjayi - They are - but asking them to do something really fast `2,000,000,000,000` times is still asking a lot. :)

Comment: @AbdulwasiiAjayi - See [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Instructions_per_second) - *Intel Core i7 = 317,900 MIPS* would take about `6,290` seconds which is about `1.7` hours. I may have those calculatiopns a bit out but I guess you get the idea.

Comment: As a sidenote, there are faster prime number algorithms than yours; you basically check every number each time. You can use "dynamic programming" techniques to speed things up (basically store the prime numbers you have already calculated in a List).

Comment: I dont understand, could you send me a relevant link?

Comment: I don't have a link; the basic idea is to store all prime numbers you found in a List, and then instead of looping through all numbers like you do in the for loop, just check if n can be divided by one of the previous prime numbers (prime factorization). If not it is a prime number.

Comment: It would be better to use a sieve algorithm directly. Perhaps the dynamic programming amounts to the same, with some overhead.

Comment: Don't know which one is faster; I just wanted to point out that there are faster implementations in general (dp being one of them).

Answer (score 1):

Why not use `isProbablePrime()` method from `BigInteger` class, if you using it anyway ?

```
for (int i = 2; i < 2000000; i++) {
        if (new BigInteger(Integer.toString(i)).isProbablePrime(10)) {
            answer = answer.add(BigInteger.valueOf(i));

        }
}
```

This code runs only for around `4` seconds.

But if you want to do by your method, you should optimize it. It's necessary to check for divisors until  `sqrt(n)`

```
for(int i = 3; i * i <= n ; i+= 2) {
    if(n % i == 0) {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Or you can use the [Sieve of Eratosthenes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes) to solve your problem

Comment: Better to use `i * i <= n` - squaring is much faster that `sqrt`. Also `i += 2` as no even numbers are prime.

Comment: And - obviously - `int i = 3` - sorry, should've mentioned that.